# cosine of fraction of an angle in terms of the cartesian components

Tags: trigonometry, polar-coordinates, angle

Given,

$\cos\theta=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$,

how can you write 
$\cos\frac{\theta}{n}$ (n an integer for simplicity) 
in terms of x and y? 
For example, one may say
$\cos\frac{\theta}{n}=?\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+(y/n)^2}}$

Comment: Cannot write that way. You can use DeMoivre's thm for fractional index as a  trigonometric series for sin/cos parts of $ e^{i \theta/n}$

Comment: suppose $t=\frac{\theta}{n}$, then $$\cos nt = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

Comment: I don't get @JohnJoy comment?

Answer (score 2):

Provided that $x$ and $y$ are suitable numbers (I think $y\geq 0$ and $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$ might be enough), you could write 
$$\cos \frac\theta n 
= \cos\left(\frac1n \arccos\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)\right).$$

If there were a "nice" way to do it using multiplication, division, addition,
subtraction, and square roots, then you could trisect an angle in
classical geometry. But that cannot be done.